# How can I join county data from a spreadsheet to a county shape file on ArcGIS?

Tags: geolocation, arcgis, shapefile

When I input the county data from the spreadsheet on ArcGIS, it shows as point data, while I am trying to make it show as geometric, thus needing to connect it to a shape file.

Have been trying to geographically link it, and do joins but, is only showing a random point, or no calculation at all. I want to get it to shade the shape of the county rather than show up as pints in the vicinity of the county.